# Incorrect conversion from char

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote a simple program which simulates clicking particular button. I strive to convert 'a' to 0x41.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#define WINVER 0x0500


int main() {


    INPUT ip;

    // Pause for 5 seconds.
    Sleep(5000);

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Press the "A" key
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Release the "A" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));



    return 0;
}
```

After compiling and executing following code It does clicking "a" which is correct. But when I change value in **ip.ki.wVk** to for ex. (int)'a' it acts different.

```
ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; //gives me "a" which is correct

ip.ki.wVk = 65 //the same as above which is good;
```

but

```
ip.ki.wVk = int('a')//gives "1";
```

Comment: What happens if you just use `ip.ki.wVk = 'a'`?

Comment: `'a'` is `0x61` and `061` is `'1'` either a strange coincidence or a typo somewhere

Comment: virtual key code is not the same as ascii character. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by `"gives "1"`? Do you mean it gives the number one? Or the digit `1`? Or something else?

Comment: Not related to your question but `#define WINVER 0x0500` should be before `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mean It's like you push 1 on your numeric keyboard.

Comment: @tobi303 strange coincidence. `VK_NUMPAD1` == `0x61`.

Comment: Those who do not understand, why passing `1` as the first argument to [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) is wrong, should not be using it until they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

`ip.ki.wVk = int('A')`

The virtual key code represents ASCII value of the letter in UPPERCASE value. Hence 'a' is turning to be the wrong key value.

The list of virtual keys mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)

'a' = 97 = 0x61 is Virtual-Key code for 'Numeric keypad 1 key`.

Comment: Yeah! It worked! Since 'A' = 41 = 0x41 is Virtual-Key code for "a" button.